# Node Js multiple form submits gives cannot post error

Tags: html, node.js

I'm using Node Js and I have couple of html pages. On every html page I have a form and when pressing submit I want to switch to the next html page. It works only for the first time and then I get an error 'cannot post'. Meaning it gets the first html page but never the second.

My app.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const log=require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger();
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('intro.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server is running on ' + port);
});

app.post('/userID', function(req, res){
  return res.sendfile('main.html');
});

app.post('/submit1', function(req, res){
  return res.sendfile('main2.html');
});

 app.post('/submit2', function(req, res){
  return res.sendfile('main3.html');
});
```

My first html:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/submit1"
   <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" id="submit"/>
  </form>
```

My second html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit2"
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed" name="submit" id="submit"/>
   </form>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It would be good if you put this in a git repository so we can run the code

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a get for main.html, main2.html and main3.html then as a response of each post do a redirect to the proper route. sending the file back as a response from the post will not tell the page to reload the sent html.